# Publisher file problems

Tags: c#, publisher-policy

I have a very similar issue to this post here:

[Release not working, referencing FW 2.0 dll into FW 4.0 winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538894/release-not-working-referencing-fw-2-0-dll-into-fw-4-0-winform)

I have a 3.5 version of an app that is using publisher files in the GAC.  When I deploy this to my dev server everything works fine however when I converted this application to 4.0 and deploy this to my dev server (still referencing  3.5 assemblies in the GAC) my application seems to be ignoring my policy files.

I have tried just about everything I can think of:

-adding/removing

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
    </startup>
```

-making sure everything references the gac dlls
-deploying in both anycpu and x86 versions

This will work if I manually add:

in the config file but that kind of defeats the purpose of my policy doesn't it?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: sorry this cut out <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="mydll" publicKeyToken="D36r5002FB8EA16" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.0.0" newVersion="2.5.0.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>

Comment: .NET 4.0 got a new GAC, now stored in c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly instead of c:\windows\assembly.  It isn't very clear how you deployed your publisher policy files, but getting them in the wrong GAC is an explanation of course.  Do keep in mind that it is a weapon of last resort, you should never need them when you moved to 4.0.  And doesn't have anything to do with a bindingRedirect.

Comment: I realize that 4.0 is in a new GAC directory. My app is a 4.0 application but it is still referencing assenblies in the old gac.  Since these are 2.0 assemblies, I am guessing that the policy files still need to stick in the 2.0 gac.  Is that an incorrect assumption?